# What determines whether a state_pressed drawable displays immediately or after a short delay?

Tags: android, button, gesture, touch-event, drawerlayout

The buttons in my app immediately display their state_pressed drawable when I tap them quickly, but only after about 300ms when I touch and hold them. I'm using a drawerlayout, and have noticed the same behavior in other apps with the drawerlayout. Other apps, eg, the calculator, display their state_pressed drawable immediately. Where is this determined?

I suspect it has to do with detecting longclicks or flings, possibly to enable opening the navigation drawer.

I'm only interested in increasing the responsiveness of the visual feedback when touching and holding a button, not its function. So it seems like the simplest solution might be to somehow manually display the drawable immediately, even though the system is still waiting to see what kind of gesture it is.

Thanks!

(Edit) Figured it out:

`public boolean shouldDelayChildPressedState ()`

> Added in API level 14
>
> Return true if the pressed state should be delayed for children or descendants of this ViewGroup. Generally, this should be done for containers that can scroll, such as a List. This prevents the pressed state from appearing when the user is actually trying to scroll the content. The default implementation returns true for compatibility reasons. Subclasses that do not scroll should generally override this method and return false.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time! Great work!